# Create nested dictionary from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, scripting

I have some data in a csv that when opened looks like this:

```
Example Data
['', 'Name', 'Phone', 'Address', 'City', 'Country', 'Email']
['1', 'Bob Myers', '410-504-5887', '12334 Hamilton Way', 'Toronto', 'Canada', 'bob@gmail.com']
['2', 'Carlton James', '455-323-8479', '1234 James Rd', 'New York', 'USA', 'carlton@example.com']
['3', 'Frank Wright', '744-521-9874', '567 Travis St', 'Boston', 'USA', 'fw4322@yahoo.com']
```

I want to create a nested dictionary where I take the integer in '' and use it as a key for each nested dictionary. I found a few similar questions and tried:

```
import csv
f = csv.DictReader(open('data.csv'))

result = {}
for row in f:
    key = row.pop('')
    result[key] = row
print(result)
```

Which yielded something like:

```
{'1': {'Name': 'Bob Myers', 'Phone': '410-504-5887', 'Address': '12334 Hamilton Way', 'City': 'Toronto',
'Country': 'Canada', 'Email': 'bob@gmail.com'}...
```

What do I change in my code to get my data to look something like this (without pandas):

```
my_dict = {{'Name': {1: 'Bob Myers', 2: 'Carlton James', 3: 'Frank Wright'}}, 
 {'Phone': {1: '410-504-5887', 2: '455-323-8479', 3: '744-521-9874'}}, 
 {'Address': {1: '12334 Hamilton Way', 2: '1234 James Rd', 3: '567 Travis St'}},
 {'City': {1: 'Toronto', 2: 'New York', 3: 'Boston'}},
 {'Country': {1: 'Canada', 2: 'USA', 3: 'USA'}},
 {'Email': {1: 'bob@gmail.com', 2: 'carlton@example.com', 3: 'fw4322@yahoo.com'}}
}
```

Comment: What do you need the desired result for? In this structure it looks like it's going to give you some troubles working with it.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the same results you had with the CSV you added.

Comment: I have json data in that structure which I plan to join to it. I thought that might be the best way to pull some exploratory data from the fields. If, for example, I want to know all of the unique countries in the set.

Comment: Why use dicts that have sequential integers for the keys, when you could just use a list?

Comment: I have three sets of data and thought to change one rather than 2. But it looks like I may have to change the others as well..

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to (ab)use Pandas ;-)

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame([result]).to_dict()
print(d)
```

For test case `result`:

```
{'1': {'Name': 'Bob Myers', 'Phone': '410-504-5887', 'Address': '12334 Hamilton Way', 'City': 'Toronto',
'Country': 'Canada', 'Email': 'bob@gmail.com'}
```

Output is like:

```
{'Name': {0: 'Bob Myers'}, 'Phone': {0: '410-504-5887'}, 'Address': {0: '12334 Hamilton Way'}, 'City': {0: 'Toronto'}, 'Country': {0: 'Canada'}, 'Email': {0: 'bob@gmail.com'}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately here I cannot use pandas.